# Improve nested forEach

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, foreach

I have this nested array:

```
const users = [
    ['User_1', [[1596232800000, 4]]],
    [
        'User_2',
        [
            [1591567200000, 3],
            [1591653600000, 16],
        ],
    ],
]
```

and would like this output:

```
const dataByDate = [
    {
        user: 'User_2',
        date: 1591567200000,
        count: 3,
    },
    {
        user: 'User_2',
        date: 1591653600000,
        count: 16,
    },
    {
        user: 'User_1',
        date: 1596232800000,
        count: 4,
    },
]
```

To achieve this I am doing this:

```
    const dataByDate: { date: string; count: number; user: string }[] = []

    users.forEach((user: string[]) => {
        if (user[1].length) {
            user[1].forEach((item: any) => {
                dataByDate.push({ date: item[0], user: user[0], count: item[1] })
            })
        }
    })
```

My solution works fine but I am wondering if there is a cleaner and more elegant solution than a nested forEach. Thanks!

Comment: [`Array.prototype.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

Comment: Does order matter?

Comment: Ideally it would be ordered by count

Comment: @suuuriam so your output array is in the wrong order then ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) with an inner [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). The inner `.map()` will take the second element of your inner array (ie: the `[[date, count], ...]` arrays), and map them to objects. Since `.map()` will result in an array of objects, you can use `.flatMap()` to merge the resulting objects into one final resulting array.

See example below:

```js
const users = [
    ['User_1', [[1596232800000, 4]]],
    [
        'User_2',
        [
            [1591567200000, 3],
            [1591653600000, 16],
        ],
    ],
];

const result = users.flatMap(([user, arr]) => arr.map(([date, count]) => ({
  user, date, count
})));
console.log(result);
```

You can then apply the `.sort()` method for any additional reordering of the output array.

Answer (score 2):

Use a combination of [`Array.prototype.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). The reduce loops over each data set for a user and creates and object per entry in that set. That object is then combined in the accumulating array.

Now `flatMap` returns a new array with objects for each user. The amount of objects are dependant on the amount of `[date, count]` entries and will be in a nested array. The flat part of `flatMap` takes care of this by putting every object in a single array.

```js
const users = [
  [
    'User_1', [
      [1596232800000, 4]
    ]
  ],
  [
    'User_2', [
      [1591567200000, 3],
      [1591653600000, 16],
    ],
  ],
];

const formatUserData = users => users.flatMap(([ user, data ]) => 
  data.reduce((arr, [ date, count ]) => 
    [...arr, { user, date, count }], [])
  );
  
const result = formatUserData(users);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using map and array destructuring, you can achieve this as:

```
const result = users
   .map(([ user, items ]) => {
      return items.flatMap(([date, count]) => ({ user, date, count }))
   })
   .flatMap(i => i)
   .sort((a,b) => a.date - b.date);
```

```js
const users = [
        ['User_1', [[1596232800000, 4]]],
        [
            'User_2',
            [
                [1591567200000, 3],
                [1591653600000, 16],
            ],
        ],
    ]

const result = users.map(([ user, items ]) => {
  return items.flatMap(([date, count]) => ({ user, date, count }))
}).flatMap(i => i).sort((a,b) => a.date - b.date);

console.log({result})
```